# reversing of a string

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
char * reverse (char *);
int main()
{
    char * a;
    cout<<"enter string"<<endl;
    gets(a);
    cout<<a;
    cout<<"the reverse of string is"<<reverse(a);
    return 0;
}
char * reverse (char * b)
{
    int i,j=strlen(b);
    for(i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        char temp;
        temp=b[j-i-1];
        b[j-i-1]=b[i];
        b[i]=temp;
    }
    return b;
}
```

This program is giving no compile time error.But it does give run time error and does not give desired output. Please explain the cause.As I am not that much good in C++ so please forgive me if my question is not upto mark.

Comment: What is the runtime error? And what is the output?

Comment: There is no C++ other than cout.

Comment: @taskinoor - Not so.  Or at least, I'm fairly certain that there is no `cout`, stream `<<` operator, `endl`, or `using namespace` in C.

Comment: Please don't use `gets`.  If you want to use a `<cstdio>` function, use `fgets()` so you can specify a size.  With `gets` your user can inadvertently or purposefully overrun the buffer. (Edit: Sorry, cnicutar had already said this in his answer)

Comment: @aroth, what I meant is that C++ is only used for outputting, but C++ string is not used. <<, endl and namespace can be removed if printf() is used instead of cout. Hopefully I am clear now :-P

Comment: Note that in theory, this could be done in-place by swapping `char`s two by two, either using iterators or raw pointers (which aren't all that different for a C++0x `std::string` anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not allocating memory for the string. `gets` doesn't allocate memory for you, so you're just reading into some random location - results are undefined.

Apart from that, there are more problems:

- This is tagged C++ but it's more like C with cout (using `string` would be a better idea)
- You are using `gets` instead of `fgets`. `gets` is quite dangerous and should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::cout<<"enter string"<<endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "The reverse of a string is ";
    std::copy(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
    return 0;
}
```

The Standard provides string handling that isn't insane like the C-strings you're trying to use, and it also provides reverse iteration quite trivially. In this model you don't have to allocate your own memory or do your own reversal.

Comment: `+1` from me for a real C++ solution. (An alternative, and maybe easier for beginners, would be to use `std::reverse()` and `std::cout << a`.)

Comment: Didn't even know that existed. I've never heard of a `std::reverse` :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate space for the first string otherwise you are pointing to the ether and overwriting God only knows what space.  But, to be more idiomatic C++ may I suggest you use a standard string?  Simply replace the char* with std::string.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, you are actually reversing your string twice. You have to walk only half of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/) on the proper usage of `gets()`.  You can't pass it an uninitialized `char*` and expect anything good to happen.  You might have better luck with:

```
char a[256];
cout<<"enter string"<<endl;
gets(a);
```

Comment: @DeadMG - For a simple throw-away example of how to reverse a string (which is probably CS-101 homework) magic numbers are perfectly acceptable.  And if you want to be really pedantic, using `gets()` is not the right solution either.  Nor character arrays, for that matter (might as well use `string` instead).

Comment: @aroth: In my class I would regularly check submitted code against very long strings and subtract points for any program that would crash, rather than exit gracefully.

Comment: @aroth: No, they're not. There are some habits that you never, ever teach people for any reason, and magic-number C-string handling is one of them. Even if you have to interact with legacy code, `std::string` can deal with conversions back and forth. There's no excuse.

Comment: @thkala - That's fine if you're teaching third- and fourth-year students, but if you are doing that to CS-101 level students then I feel sorry for them.  We're talking about people who are just learning the fundamental concepts of Computer Science here.  Penalizing them for not understanding vagaries related to memory management and creating applications that never ever crash doesn't make sense.

Comment: @aroth: So when a program that reads its input character-by-character goes beyond an array of known length it's fine if it's in CS-101? And the solution to *that* crash is to use an array of 10,000 characters instead of 500? Sounds like teaching students a lot of bad habits - like not watching their array bounds. We barely touch upon anything more than arrays in our introductory course, but we do expect the students to work with them correctly.

Comment: @thkala - If the purpose of the assignment is to get students exposure to basic concepts like function calls, string manipulation, and I/O, then yes, unless the assignment explicitly states that the program should be able to handle arbitrarily long inputs (and unless the course explicitly covers the correct way to do so) it's fine if the program can't.  It has nothing to do with "teaching bad habits".  It's more like not assuming that students will have good habits until they are *taught* to have good habits.  Not penalizing for something is not the same as teaching it.

Comment: @aroth: Our students *are* taught the correct way to work with issues such as this and the assignments typically contain explicit requirements for e.g. appropriate error messages to be printed. Unfortunately not every student does as they are taught, especially with the Internet being full of braindead code samples.