# reversing a string in place

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool compare( const string::size_type i, const string::size_type j )
{
    cout << "comparing " << i << " and " << j << "." << endl;
    return i < j;
}

void reverse_inplace( std::string &s )
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0;
    std::string::size_type j = s.size()-1;
    cout << "called" << endl;
    while( compare(i,j) );
    {
        cout << i << " " << j << endl;
        std::swap(s[i], s[j]);
        ++i;
        --j;
        cout << i << " " << j << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s( "a" );
    reverse_inplace(s);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Why will it keep comparing, return true? and not execute the loop body there's no ? I tried GCC 4.6 and MSVC 10 SP1. The `cout` statements in the loop are not being executed for some strange reason.

Comment: This probably isn't relevant to the problem, but you want to initialize `j` to `s.size() - 1`.  The last valid index is always one less than the size.

Comment: @Maxpm: I wasn't sure, would have discovered that when the code ran, which it didn't. Thanks though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The loop body isn't being executed because you have a semicolon after the while() line, which is causing the loop body to be ignored. Therefore, the increment and decrement statements aren't being hit; neither are the `cout`s.

Comment: Oh dang. Yes indeed. Why are there no warnings for this case :(. Thanks!

Comment: Because empty loop bodies are not only valid but sometimes useful constructs.

Comment: @Ferruccio: please explain? Surely the presence of at least `{}` would not hurt that usefulness, and prevent situations such as mine?

Comment: In the case of `for()` loops especially, you can do a lot in the loop itself, so sometimes you won't need the body. As far as my experience goes, a situation like yours exists because of the "responsibility of the programmer" meme. Although I think there may be a GCC flag that would display a warning, if memory serves.

Comment: Technically, the "loop body" is not being ignored. What the OP thinks is the loop body is actually an unrelated block statement.

Comment: I think I recall that the compiler, upon detecting that there is a semicolon there, will not bother with the loop body, so it is being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove the semicolon after the `while` statement.

Second, you should initialize `j` with `s.size()-1`, if not, it points to an invalid index at the beginning (`1` in your case, which is after the end of the string). This can result in a number of unexpected results. Note, that you'll have to check for `s.size()==0` in this case, since `size_t` is unsigned, and `s.size()-1` would give an underflow for an empty string.

Third, you should have a look st `std::reverse()`, if you need this in production code :)

Comment: aha, `std::reverse`. Where were you for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640733/reversing-of-a-string